# Difference between a metric sphere and a topological sphere

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Recently I encountered a mysterious term named "metric $2$-sphere". Does it have anything to do with a metric space? If it is typically used to refer to a sphere in *any* metric space, why should I mention the number $2$? Is it like the superscript $n$ in the $n$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$?

As to a "topological sphere", this is probably a concept that is easier to understand. After I googled this term, it seems to represent a topological space that is homeomorphic to a sphere in a Euclidean space w.r.t. the subspace topology.

Then, what is a metric $2$-sphere supposed to mean? Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly did you read about metric spheres?

Comment: @PaulFrost Hello, I'm reading an article about general relativity, a theory that deals with gravitation. And the author is mentioning a "metric $2$-sphere in the $4$-dimensional spacetime".

Comment: I would interpret "metric 2-sphere" as "Riemannian manifold that is isometric to the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ endowed with the induced Riemannian metric".

Comment: If "topological sphere" means "space homeomorphic to sphere" then I would expect "metric sphere" to mean "metric space isometric to sphere". But honestly, the author should've explained this. It is definitely not a standard nomenclature.

Comment: If it is in a GR article, then the author can mean absolutely anything by a "metric sphere," especially since the word "metric" in GR has a different meaning from the one in math. For instance, the author might mean an embedded 2-sphere equipped with the pull-back of the metric tensor from the ambient space-time. As for a "topological sphere," the author most likely means a smooth 2-dimensional manifold diffeomorphic to the standard round sphere. The word "topological" here simply means that no metric tensor or conformal structure (or any other geometric structure) is given.

Comment: I wonder if you’d have more luck cross posting on the physics stack exchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm thinking its just the boundary of a metric ball (say $\partial B_{\epsilon}(x_0) := \{x\text{ }|\text{ }d(x_0,x)=\epsilon\}$). With the subtlety being that the author knows that somehow this set is 2D? We kind of need explicit metric form to see.